# Multi-trunked elephants invade Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens, nuclear-weapons

I read this novel at least 25 years ago, maybe more. I don't remember the cover.

There is a joke:
How does an elephant come down from a tree ? It sits on a leaf and waits for autumn.

Well, this is how this book begins, by an army of elephant-looking aliens reaching Earth on gliders. And soon they control most of it.

One thing that I remember is that with them everything went by three (or maybe by four ?): their trunks that ended in many delicate "fingers", 9 or more  (16?)  ; their armies that were organized in a hierarchy by 3 or 4; and so on.

I don't remember much except that those who on Earth tried to keep fighting managed to leave the surface by a rather brutal method: huge (and very thick) metallic plates propelled by exploding nuclear bombs on their down side. (I don't  remember how they manage to explode nuclear bombs progressively rather than all the bombs at once).

I think that by that method, once the "elephants" lose full control of the sky, mankind manages to win the war.

Comment: Definitely _Footfall_ as stated in the answer below. I stayed up all night reading it when it was new. As to delivering bombs one at a time, if a soda machine can deliver one soda at a time to a customer, then surely the Orion engineers can figure out how to deliver one bomb at a time below the plate.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron The soda machine does not deliver one soda in a zone where an atomic bomb has just exploded... ;)

Comment: For the atom bomb-spaceship: This is also a real NASA design. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion). They even did some bit of testing for the concept, before it was shelved for obvious reasons

Comment: @Alfred Here's an extract from the link provided by Hobbamok: "A preliminary design for a nuclear pulse unit was produced. ... The whole unit was built into a can with a diameter no larger than 6 inches (150 mm) and weighed just over 300 pounds (140 kg) so it could be handled by machinery scaled-up from a soft-drink vending machine; Coca-Cola was consulted on the design.[26]" Yeah, I thought I remembered that, but it seemed too bizarre to cite without some kind of backup. Thanks, Hobbamok. One obvious problem: How do you fix it if it jams in mid-flight?

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm reading Footfall (for the first time) *right now*. It doesn't "begin" with elephants on gliders, though; I'm on Chapter 11 (about 25%) and no gliders yet, and only a very brief appearance of the aliens. The first quarter of the book is all about humans noticing their ship and "preparing" for it.

Comment: At first I guessed that the story might have been Fletcher Pratt's "The Onslaught from Ribel" Thrilling Wonder Stories, 1932, exapanded into Invaders from Rigel, 1960, since the Lassans from Rigel look sort of like elephants.

Comment: There was a network that advertised the football games it showed with the slogan "Are you ready for the football?"   And so I wonder if anyone in the novel asks:  "Are you ready for the footfall?"

Comment: @Matthew As I have written, I read this 25 years ago or more. What I remembered was the arrival of the... Fithp, as I have now ascertained, multi-trunked elephants as I remembered when I asked my question. The beginning of the book did not leave as strong an impression in my memory as the gliders....

Comment: As Valorum says, it's *Footfall*.  Not the greatest sci-fi novel of all time, perhaps, but the most outright entertaining invasion-of-the-Earth story ever, IMHO.

Comment: Indeed, the chapters before the Fithp actually show up are... not the most engaging reading . I'm somewhat impressed you remember the gliders, though; the book didn't (or at least hasn't so far) made a big deal of them. (Sigh. Thanks all for spoiling the Orion drive .)

Comment: @Matthew Sorry for the spoilers.... But if I want an answer, I have to describe the book.... As for remembering the gliders, I suppose it was because of the joke "How does the elephant come down fro a tree". That one, I heard even **more** than 25 years ago, and the gliders struck a chord.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is *[Footfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footfall)* by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle.

> The alien Fithp resemble baby elephants with multiple prehensile
> trunks. They possess more advanced technology than humans, but did not
> develop any of it on their own. In the distant past on their planet,
> another species was dominant. The predecessor species badly damaged
> the environment, rendering itself and many other species extinct, but
> left behind their knowledge inscribed on large stone cubes from which
> the Fithp gained their technology. An arms race between two rival
> herds threatened to render the species extinct, so they wagered to see
> who would depart in a starship and seek a new home elsewhere. The
> leadership of the loser formed the Chtaptisk Fithp ('Traveling Herd').
> ...
> **The US secretly builds a large, heavily armed spacecraft in Washington state that is propelled by nuclear bombs**, a real concept known as Project Orion
>
> [image]

For the record, the alien's society appears to be based on the number eight

> “There were eights of eight-cubed of thuktunthp scattered about the
> world. The Predecessors.
> ...
> They would drown, by eight to the eighths. The Herdmaster mourned in advance. “Have you chosen our foothold?’

Comment: This is indeed it. But Wikipedia does not mention the number on which their society was organised, which is an important point I remember. But was it 3 ? 4 ? 9 ?

Comment: "*“There were eights of eight-cubed of thuktunthp scattered about the world. The Predecessors*"

Comment: *A line of insect-sized flyers converged toward the town ahead. Those weren't parachutes. "Delta wings," Harry Red murmured. "Hang gliders." The shapes hanging under the delta wings were not human.*

Comment: @DavidW Sorry for you, looks like Valorum won the race ;)

Comment: @Alfred I seem to remember it's 8 because their trunk splits in two, then in two again, then in two again, so they have 8 "fingers".

Comment: Really an very good book, some interesting ideas with the invaders, and more variety and depth in the humans than a lot of invasion epics

Comment: The "Science Fiction writers get asked by the US Government to advise them" also happened for real - but I don't remember if the book came first. I know that Larry Niven was involved in a post-9/11 government thinktank (obviously after the book) but I think there was an earlier "Strategic Defence Initiative" (a.k.a. StarWars) era one too - which would be around the time he wrote the book...

Comment: @AdamT Was at a panel discussion a few years a back where David Brin said he was on such an SF writers advisory panel and claimed that, among other things, they thought up a meme (the idea, not a Twitter graphic) that would bring about societal collapse if allowed to spread.

Comment: @jeffronicus, sounds similar to [The Funniest Joke In the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Funniest_Joke_in_the_World).  

Comment: @N.Virgo Thank you. But as a matter of fact, while the number 8 was not mentioned  in Valorum's **original** answer when I asked what number that was, he did edit his answer to add this info just a few minutes after I had asked for it.

Comment: @Alfred sure, I just wanted to add the extra in-universe information about why it was 8, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Got to love that [Michael Whelan cover art](https://www.michaelwhelan.com/galleries/footfall/)...

Comment: @N.Virgo I did not mean to be offensive. In fact, my previous suggestions of 4 and 9 were based on the vague memory that the trunks were first split in a  prime number of branches then re-split in the **same** prime number of subbranches. I just forgot they were split a third time, as per your info.